# How do I include FFMpeg for development in a windows program?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, ffmpeg, pkg-config

I'm trying to follow a tutorial about using the FFMpeg libraries to extract frames from videos in C++ ([by Bartholomew](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Yx3injNZs)).

In order to include the libraries, according to the tutorial, it is advised to use pkg-config to find the libraries and put them together so that CMake can include them. In the video he uses homebrew to install ffmpeg and somehow pkg-config is able to find the header files for ffmpeg (libavcodec, libavformat, libavdevice ...)

The problem is I don't know how to get the ffmpeg libraries installed so that pkg-config can find them.

On windows, I've tried installing the compiled windows binaries, and I've tried installing ffmpeg-full package using chocolatey. However, I fail to see where these header files are installed to.

There's a ffmpeg folder in `C:/ffmpeg/` but when I look in that there's no header files or libraries, just the binaries. Perhaps I need to clone the entire source project, but then how is pkg-config supposed to find them? When I try and compile I get this output:

```
 Found PkgConfig: C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/pkg-config.bat (found version "0.26") 
 Checking for module 'libavcodec'
 Can't find libavcodec.pc in any of C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig
 use the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, or
 specify extra search paths via 'search_paths'
 CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
 A required package was not found
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
 lib/FFMpeg/CMakeLists.txt:5 (pkg_check_modules)
 Checking for module 'libavcodec'        <----- here
 Can't find libavcodec.pc in any of C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig
 use the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable, or
 specify extra search paths via 'search_paths'
 CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:607 (message):
 A required package was not found
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
 C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.24/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:829 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
 lib/FFMpeg/CMakeLists.txt:5 (pkg_check_modules)
```

The contents of `C:/Strawberry/c/lib/pkgconfig` seem to be a whole load of libraries none of which are from ffmpeg.

In case the problem is in my CMakeLists file, here are the contents of the subdirectory file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(FFMpeg)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(AVCODEC    REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavcodec)
pkg_check_modules(AVFILTER   REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavformat)
pkg_check_modules(AVDEVICE   REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavdevice)
pkg_check_modules(AVUTIL     REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libavutil)
pkg_check_modules(SWRESAMPLE REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libswresample)
pkg_check_modules(SWSCALE    REQUIRED    IMPORTED_TARGET libswscale)

add_library(FFMpeg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_include_directories(
    FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVFILTER_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVDEVICE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${AVUTIL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SWSCALE_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_options(
    FFmpeg INTERFACE
    ${AVCODEC_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVFILTER_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVDEVICE_LDFLAGS}
    ${AVUTIL_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWRESAMPLE_LDFLAGS}
    ${SWSCALE_LDFLAGS}
)
```

What have I done wrong/am not understanding?